# debugging admin_data on heroku rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, authorization

I keep getting the error "not authorized" whenever i try to visit:

```
appname.herokuapp.com/admin_data
```

I've created an admin.rb file with

```
AdminData.config do |config|
    #comment
    config.is_allowed_to_view = lambda {|controller| return true if (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?) }
end
```

(I know the above following has a safety issue but I'm just trying to get it work before I check for administration.)

I've tried

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and also

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

prior to pushing to heroku but i can't seem to get past that error.

I've followed the instructions from

https://github.com/bigbinary/admin_data

but can't seem to get it to work on production.

On my development machine it works.

http://localhost:3000/admin_data shows everything belonging to my dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that your heroku instance is in production mode? Sometimes instances on Heroku are configured as `staging`.

Try this:

```
heroku config --app your_app_name
```

This will return the config variables of your instance. You will see a variety of config variables. Look for these:

```
RACK_ENV             => production
RAILS_ENV            => production
```

Are they set to `production` or `staging`?

Comment: hmm they are both set to production

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the Production Configuration section of https://github.com/bigbinary/admin_data/wiki/admin_data-security-configuration-for-a-Rails3-application - seems like there are extra steps you need to take when your application is running in production mode.

Comment: hmm i read that too but it doesn't seem like i need to do any additional steps. what steps were you referring to? on my config code, im not using any helper methods so i dont think i need to declare them

Answer (score 0):

ah it was a dumb mistake. i was not pushing from my master branch and my app was never being updated